# ¿Como puedo traducir los datos entrantes de una base de datos con thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

Tengo la siguente tabla, y necesito que los datos del campo `contract_type` se muestren como `pasante` o `empleado` los cuales se guardan como `intern` y `employee` respectivamente. gracias anticipadas.

```
<th:block th:each="person : ${persons}">
        <tr>
            <td th:text="${person.name}"></td>
            <td th:text="${person.last_name}"></td>
            <td th:text="${person.birth}"></td>
            <td th:text="${person.birth_place}"></td>
            <td th:text="${person.movil_phone}"></td>
            <td th:text="${person.civil_state}"></td>
            <td th:text="${person.nationality}"></td>
            <td th:text="${person.cuil}"></td>
            <td th:text="${person.email}"></td>
            <td th:text="${person.address}"></td>
            <td th:text="${person.address_number}"></td>
            <td th:text="${person.floor}"></td>
            <td th:text="${person.department}"></td>
            <td th:text="${person.contract_type}"></td>//este campo 
            <td th:text="${person.leaveDate}"></td>
        </tr>
    </th:block>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el criterio que usas para establecer que el "tipo de contrato" es Pasante o Empleado?

Comment: ya lo solucione con un swich <p th:case="'employe'">Empleado</p> gracias igual

Answer (score 0):

No pones que criterio usas, así que yo usaría algo como esto
0 -> Pasante
1 -> Empleado

```
<td th:text="${person.contract_type==0?'Pasante' : 'Empleado'}"></td>
```